# The origin and use of the term "equianharmonic" (elliptic function)

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology, elliptic-functions

This question has been posted on History of Science and Mathematics stack exchange, but there was no answer or comments there.

In Weierstrass notation, the principal elliptic function $\wp$ is a solution of the equation
$$(\wp')^2=4\wp^3-g_2\wp-g_3.$$
The case when $g_3=0$ is called [lemniscatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_elliptic_functions) (it corresponds to a square lattice), and the case $g_2=0$ is called [equianharmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equianharmonic) (it corresponds to a hexagonal lattice). The origin of the first term is clear: it comes from the problem on the length of the [Bernoulli's lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli).

What is the origin of the term "equianharmonic"?

The term "equianharmonic" seems out of date: checking Google ngram shows a strange pattern: its usage experienced a peak around 1860 and was much more frequent than "lemniscatic" until 1980s, and nowadays it is used about 10 times less frequently than "lemniscatic". Also the sizes and details of Wikipedia articles confirm this.

Comment: This question would probably be better on [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @LSpice: I agree, but read the first 3 lines of the question.

Comment: I think this is answered at https://mathoverflow.net/a/385121/11260

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Thanks, this answers my question.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436817/the-origin-and-use-of-the-term-equianharmonic-elliptic-function#comment1125776_436817), I see, sorry.  It might be a good idea to link to the question:  [The origin and use of the term "equianharmonic" (elliptic function)](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15022/the-origin-and-use-of-the-term-equianharmonic-elliptic-function); and perhaps, @CarloBeenakker, you could post your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436817/the-origin-and-use-of-the-term-equianharmonic-elliptic-function#comment1125777_436817) as an answer?

Comment: @LSpice --- done.

Comment: @Brian Hopkins: yes, it does. This is the same ref that Carlo Beenakker gave.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The name of the equianharmonic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385100/the-name-of-the-equianharmonic-curve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to remove this question from the "unanswered list": The term "equianharmonic" refers to "equal anharmonic ratio", as explained by Wiener in 1901, see this earlier [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385121/11260).

Comment: The term could not be possibly introduced so late (see Google ngram viewer).

Comment: If the answer can't possibly be right, then why have you accepted it?

Comment: edit: "introduced by Wiener" --> "explained by Wiener"